# Boolean as a prop in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am making a Vue From to ask a question. So i made an component:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2">
    <div class="flex w-[80%] items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-3xl p-2">
      <textarea
        class="w-full"
        :placeholder="ansPlaceholder"
        :value="modelValue"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      ></textarea>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        :value="checkboxValue"
        name="isTrue"
        @change="$emit('update:checkboxValue', $event.target.value)"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const props = defineProps({
  ansPlaceholder: {
    type: String,
    default: 'default'
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String
  },
  checkboxValue: {
    type: Boolean
  }
})

defineEmits(['update:modelValue', 'update:checkboxValue'])
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

and the main component:

```
<template>
  <div
    name="form container"
    class="mx-auto flex w-[70%] flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-3xl border-2 border-black"
  >
    <div name="question" class="flex w-[80%] flex-col items-center justify-center gap-3 p-3">
      <p class="text-2xl font-semibold">Question</p>
      <textarea class="w-[80%]" placeholder="Add a question" v-model="question"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div name="border" class="mx-auto w-[50%] rounded-3xl border-2 border-gray-400"></div>
    <div name="answers" class="flex w-[80%] flex-col gap-2 p-3">
      <FormAnswer
        ansPlaceholder="Answer A"
        v-model:modelValue="answers[0]"
        v-model:checkboxValue="isTrue[0]"
      ></FormAnswer>
      <FormAnswer
        ansPlaceholder="Answer B"
        v-model:modelValue="answers[1]"
        v-model:checkboxValue="isTrue[1]"
      ></FormAnswer>
      <!-- <FormAnswer ansPlaceholder="Answer C"></FormAnswer>
      <FormAnswer ansPlaceholder="Answer D"></FormAnswer>
      <FormAnswer ansPlaceholder="Answer E"></FormAnswer> -->

      <select>
        <option value="">Database 1</option>
        <option value="">Database 2</option>
      </select>
      <button
        class="mx-auto mt-2 w-fit rounded-3xl border-2 border-black p-3 text-xl font-semibold transition-all duration-500 hover:scale-105 hover:bg-black hover:text-white"
        @click="getFormData()"
      >
        Submit question
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import FormAnswer from '../AdminDashboardCmp/FormAnswer.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
const question = ref('')
const answers = []
const isTrue = ref('')

function getFormData() {
  console.log(answers)
}
</script>

<style scoped></style
```

the goal is to console log the answer as na object { answer:'lorem ipsum', isTrue: false } and if i click the checkbox { answer:'lorem ipsum', isTrue: true}. But i dont know to pass boolean as a prop.

```
   <textarea
        class="w-full"
        :placeholder="ansPlaceholder"
        :value="modelValue"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      ></textarea>
```

then

```
const props = defineProps({
  ansPlaceholder: {
    type: String,
    default: 'default'
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String
  },

defineEmits(['update:modelValue', 'update:checkboxValue'])
```

and

```
   <FormAnswer
        ansPlaceholder="Answer A"
        v-model:modelValue="answers[0]"
        v-model:checkboxValue="isTrue[0]"
      ></FormAnswer>
```

worked for passing text, but not boolean. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isTrue` value is of type string, so the `isTrue[0]` and `isTrue[1]` are not booleans.
Try to initialize it to be an array.

Instead of `const isTrue = ref('')` try to use this `const isTrue = reactive([true, false])`

Comment: i will try it! thanks sir for answer and for your time!